# How to stop select same row in different queries

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to fetch the sql server table records using linq-to-entity query with two instances.
I'm getting same record in two instaces which should not done in my case.
If one instance pics one record that record should not pick in another instance.
Can any one guide me to achive this.

Comment: Post your query and we can guide you.

Comment: Is it an SQL Server query? or a linq-to-entity query? Please provide more details in the question - like, the query you are trying, and where you have placed the query.

Comment: @Nirman its a Linq query. I mean can we put any lock on table so that it wont pick on the other instance

Comment: if you are running both SQL queries in a single batch, then you can create a temporary table where you may track the IDs of the records which has been picked by first query. And then in the second query, you can use "NOT IN" within a WHERE clause to exclude those records.